# Euclidian distance with HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

I have a table on Hive with the structure below :

Sensor;Temperature;Pressure
1;23;23
2;34;45
3;45;55

and I want to know if it's possible to implement KNN algo with HiveQL UDF.
The objectif is to get as output (for k=3 for example) a table like :

Sensor;Temperature;Pressure;1stSensor;2ndSensor;3ndSensor

I appreciate you help

Soufs

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are looking for something free & open source.

There's HIVEmall, but currently, it doesn't support Euclidian distance: https://github.com/myui/hivemall

There are, however, several distance metrics that it supports.

Answer (score 0):

`euclid_distance` / `euclid_similarity` function is supported since Hivemall v0.3.2-3.

You can perform k-NN using various similarity functions (cosine_similarity , jaccard_similarity, angular_similarity, and euclid_similarity) as follows:

https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/news20-Nearest-Neighbor-(kNN)-Search#knn-search-using-minhashing

The input format will be array of string as a `features`.

```
|: rowid :|:                features               :|
-----------------------------------------------------
|    1    | [Sensor:1, Temperature:23, Pressure:23] |
|    2    | [Sensor:2, Temperature:34, Pressure:55] |
```

You need a self join as follows:

```
select
   l.rowid,
   euclid_distance(l.features, r.features) as distance
from
   mytable l 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable r
```

Note: For efficient top-k similarity listing, you can use `each_top_k` function as follows:

https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/Efficient-Top-k-computation-on-Apache-Hive-using-Hivemall-UDTF#top-k-similarity-computation